# How can you assign multiple css stylesheets to various sections of html content?

Tags: html, css

We are looking to reference multiple css stylesheets within the same page. The header will contain a nav bar with one set of stylesheets while the remaining page will need to assign a separate stylesheet. We are not allowed to change either of the stylesheets. Snippet of code below:

```
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet5">

***Apply stylesheet1 here only***
<!-- navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#" alt="Image"></a>
 <!--END NAV-->

 ***Apply stylesheet2 here only***
 <!--Content-->
 <div id="content">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <!--END CONTENT-->

 etc.....
```

Comment: Yes...next question? Although elements don't contain stylesheets the `<head>` section does. There is no reason why the stylesheets can't **apply** to specific elements only though.

Comment: How can it be applied?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the head section of your html file add your style sheets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to your css">
```

You can include as many style sheets as you wish.

Comment: How are those applied to the specific sections within the page?

Comment: In the css file you reference different elements/sections of the page. For example, if you have a <div id="myDiv"></div> tag then you can reference the div in your css with #myDiv{} and style this div element as appropriate.

Comment: Posting the css file and html file would help greatly.

Comment: Added in snippet. We want to apply different stylesheets for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can link as many CSS stylesheets you need.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
```

Comment: How can you only apply them to specific sections of the page?

Comment: Add to each one page only stylesheets you need there. If you generate page using PHP etc., use conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is not achievable and since everyone that was ripping my question in the first place vanished, I'm assuming they have no suggestions other than to completely alter the inline stylesheets to combine all elements in a single location.